# Crashing korgac in kubuntu when starting on Plasma 5.8

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma

I have dual boot. And recently installed kubuntu plasma with unity as default. It kept crashing and shows korgac crashed whenever I turn on my system. How to fix it- [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toE9V.jpg)

Other details when I try to debug the info : [read here](https://ghostbin.com/paste/9kmdx)

Specs: 64-bit Kubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Are you using the backports ppa for KDE/Plasma?  Also have you installed any out of repo python packages?

Comment: Yes, I'm using backports ppa. Yes, also installed Python packages using pip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `korganizer` (package to which `korgac` belongs) and `kontact` are obsolete and replaced by `kaddressbook` as of **4:16.04.3-0ubuntu2~ubuntu16.04~ppa63** (if not sooner, run `dpkg -S $( which korgac )` and `dpkg-query -s kaddressbook` for details).

You can safely remove `kontact` and `korganizer` using apt

Comment: Hmmm, I think I'm pretty up to date with KDE's PIM 16.12.3 (https://kubuntu.org/news/kde-pim-update-now-available-for-zesty-zapus-17-04/) on Kubuntu 17.04 which is called Kontact 5.4.3 which includes Korganizer (Calendar and Todo lists) and Kaddressbook.  It's a little confusing but perhaps the titles of the software have been switched around in some way.  Could someone clarify this?